# Fody compile error after upgrading Visual Studio

Tags: c#

My program used to compile just fine in VS2013. After upgrading to VS2015 enterprise edition, when I try to compile the program, it says:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.ReadCustomMetadata(BitAccess bits)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction..ctor(ManProcSym proc, BitAccess bits)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.LoadManagedFunctions(BitAccess bits, UInt32 limit, Boolean readStrings)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFuncsFromDbiModule(BitAccess bits, DbiModuleInfo info, IntHashTable names, ArrayList funcList, Boolean readStrings, MsfDirectory dir, Dictionary`2 nameIndex, PdbReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions(Stream read, Dictionary`2& tokenToSourceMapping, String& sourceServerData, Int32& age, Guid& guid)
   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.PopulateFunctions()
   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.ProcessDebugHeader(ImageDebugDirectory directory, Byte[] header)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader()
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols(ISymbolReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Stream stream, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at InnerWeaver.ReadModule() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\ModuleReader.cs:line 14
   at InnerWeaver.Execute() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7495521761d392b9\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 28
Source:
Mono.Cecil.Pdb
TargetSite:
Void ReadCustomMetadata(Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess)    ChampionsGG
```

I have never used fody before and never heard of it before, so i'm not sure why it would be using this. After checking the packages file there was 2 packages, Fody and Costura.Fody but I don't remember putting it there. I removed both lines and recompiled but the error still occurs.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from VS 2012 with an old version of Fody (1.26) to VS 2015 with the latest Fody (1.29.4).

So I uninstalled Fody entirely but then I got a build error from my old Fody, which should no longer have been there.

I looked in the csproj file and saw that 2 lines about my old Fody were left. I commented them out, then re-installed the latest Fody, and then everything worked again.

Comment: why down voted, obviously this is a version stability issue which is fixes in the later versions, I needed to be reminded to upgrade fody, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue of Fody. You seem to use TeamCity to build your solution. I am no TeamCity expert but the exception comes from a MS pdb parser which is used by Mono Cecil which is used by TeamCity to do ... things.

Check out this issue of Fody:
https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/187

Either wait for TeamCity to update Fody or update it by yourself or remove the custom MSBuild task which triggers the TeamCity activity.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't even heard of TeamCity. That folder doesn't even exist on my computer o_O My VS2015 is clean but I installed Resharper, is that why?

Comment: TeamCity is a Jetbrains product which also produces Resharper. Did you install some JetBrains tools suite which did perhaps also install TeamCity? You should check out unusal custom msbuild tasks and delete them like noted in the bug report on github. That should do the trick